# How to extract the output of a model in TensorFlow into a numpy array?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network

I have a GAN model in which I need to integrate the output of the generator before passing it to the discriminator. The method of integration I am choosing is `scipy.integrate.cumtrapz()`. This method keeps track of integral of every timestep so I get basically a discrete anti-derivative instead of a numeric integral. I am aware that there is a `tf.trapz()` but it will only return the numerical value. My issue is that when I pass the output of the generator `x_fake = self.generator(latent_vec)` to the `cumtrapz()`, I get an error because the generator output is a tensor not an numpy array. Okay, I get it, the input to `cumtrapz()` needs to be an array. But I cannot convert the generator output tensor `x_fake` to a numpy array because it is a symbolic tensor. I get why Keras constructs the model as symbolic initially, but when a numeric input is passed to that model, (in my case a random latent vector), why would the output still be symbolic? I can view the numeric value of this output using `tf.print()`, but that does not help as I need it in a variable. What is further confusing is that if I pass input to the generator outside of training, I get a numeric tensor with a numpy method.

I have read that this symbolic behavior happens when using the Keras Functional API, but I switched to the Sequential API for the generator model without any different behavior. I have tried running a TF Session, and got about a 1000-line error (no exaggeration). So how can I convert the generator output to a numpy array during training to perform integration?

Here is my model with loss functions:

```
def define_generator(latent_dim):
    
    inputs = Input(shape=latent_dim)
    h = Conv1DTranspose(1, 11, strides=1, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))(inputs)
    h = Conv1DTranspose(1, 11, strides=1, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))(h)
    h = Conv1DTranspose(1, 11, strides=1, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))(h)
    outputs = Conv1DTranspose(1, 12, strides=1, activation='linear')(h)
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name='GENERATOR')
    
    return model


def generator_loss(D_labels, D_pred):
    
    bce = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
    loss = bce(D_labels, D_pred)
    
    return loss


def define_discriminator(data_shape):
    
    inputs = Input(shape=data_shape)
    h = Conv1D(1, 12, strides=1, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))(inputs)
    h = Conv1D(1, 11, strides=1, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))(h)
    h = Conv1D(1, 11, strides=1, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))(h)
    h = Conv1D(1, 11, strides=1, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))(h)
    outputs = Conv1D(1, 10, strides=1, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))(h)
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name='DISCRIMINATOR')
    
    return model


def discriminator_loss(D_labels, D_pred):
    
    bce = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
    loss = bce(D_labels, D_pred)
    
    return loss
```

And here is my code for the training:

```
class define_GAN(Model):
    
    def __init__(self, gen, disc, latent_dim, n_disc_train):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.generator = gen
        self.discriminator = disc
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim
        self.n_disc_train = n_disc_train
    
    
    def compile(self, gen_loss_fcn, disc_loss_fcn, gen_lr=0.001, gen_beta1=0.9, gen_beta2=0.999, disc_lr=0.001, disc_beta1=0.9, disc_beta2=0.999):
        super().compile()
        self.gen_optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=gen_lr, beta_1=gen_beta1, beta_2=gen_beta2)
        self.disc_optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=disc_lr, beta_1=disc_beta1, beta_2=disc_beta2)
        self.gen_loss_fcn = gen_loss_fcn
        self.disc_loss_fcn = disc_loss_fcn
    
    
    def train_step(self, x_real):
        
        batch_size = tf.shape(x_real)[0]
        for i in range(self.n_disc_train):
            latent_vec = tf.random.normal(shape=(batch_size, self.latent_dim))
            x_fake = self.generator(latent_vec)
            #tf.print(x_fake)
            #x_fake = integrate.cumtrapz(x_fake.numpy(), t)
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                D_real = self.discriminator(x_real, training=True)
                y_real = tf.ones([batch_size, 1])
                D_fake = self.discriminator(x_fake, training=True)
                y_fake = tf.zeros([batch_size, 1])
                pred = tf.concat([D_real, D_fake], 0)
                label = tf.concat([y_real, y_fake], 0)
                disc_loss = self.disc_loss_fcn(label, pred)
            disc_gradient = tape.gradient(disc_loss, self.discriminator.trainable_variables)
            self.disc_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(disc_gradient, self.discriminator.trainable_variables))
        latent_vec = tf.random.normal(shape=(batch_size, self.latent_dim))
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            x_fake = self.generator(latent_vec, training=True)
            #x_fake = integrate.cumtrapz(x_fake, t)
            D_fake = self.discriminator(x_fake, training=False)
            label = tf.zeros([batch_size, 1])
            gen_loss = self.gen_loss_fcn(label, D_fake)
        gen_gradient = tape.gradient(gen_loss, self.generator.trainable_variables)
        self.gen_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gen_gradient, self.generator.trainable_variables))
        
        return {"gen_loss":gen_loss, "disc_loss":disc_loss}
```

This piece of standalone code works fine:

```
latent_vec = tf.random.normal(shape=(1,10,1))
fake = GAN.generator(latent_vec).numpy()
fake
```

I think my attempt at running a TF session was this: Wasn't sure what it was actually doing.

```
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session
with sess:
    x_fake.eval()
    sess.run(x_fake)
```

I have also tried disabling eager execution which throws an error about an unexpected keyword argument to `compile()`. The GAN will run and train without error in eager mode and without trying to convert the generator output to an array, so I don't think eager execution is an issue.

Comment: Are you able to see the contents of `x_fake`?

Comment: If I use tf.print(x_fake) after calling the generator, it will print out the values in the tensor.

Comment: Tensors usually consist of arrays. Couldn't you just get the array you needed from within the tensor?

Comment: I have tried by calling the ```numpy()``` method on  ```x_fake```. I get the error ``` AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'```.

Comment: ```x_fake.numpy()``` to be precise.

Comment: The correct function is probably `tf.make_ndarray()`. But I more so meant debug and look at the arrays contained within the tensor.

Comment: ```tf.make_ndarray(x_fake)``` returned the error: ```AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'tensor_shape' ```. According to https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/make_ndarray I tried ```proto_tensor = tf.make_tensor_proto(x_fake)``` and ```tf.make_ndarray(proto_tensor)``` and got this: ```TypeError: Expected any non-tensor type, but got a tensor instead. ``` from the second command

Comment: But when you do `tf.print(x_fake)`, you get the contents? Can't you just get that array from the tensor? I don't know the array name, but if it's called `tensorArray`, it would just be `tensor.tensorArray`. You'll need to debug to get the actual name though.

Comment: ```tf.print(x_fake)``` does let me see the values printed out. But I cannot assign the values to a numpy array variable using ```x_fake.numpy()``` or or as you suggested ```tf.make_ndarray(x_fake)```. I am not sure about the tensor's name. I usually don't name them, so it's whatever TensorFlow named it by default. I will check on it.

Comment: When I use ```print(x_fake)``` if get ```Tensor("GENERATOR/conv1d_transpose_3/BiasAdd:0", shape=(100, 51, 1), dtype=float32)```. I'm not sure if ```BiasAdd``` is the name?